# How to write a functional test for Azure File Storage file upload

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I am new to testing and wondering how to write a functional test for uploading a file to Azure File Storage and then read it back and compare the results. I have a below Azure function which does upload to file storage, but i wanted to write a functional or integration test.

```
        [FunctionName("FileServiceUpload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FileServiceUpload([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", "put", Route = "FileService/{sharename}/{directory}/{filename}")] HttpRequest req, string sharename, string directory, string filename, ILogger log)
        {
            var bodyContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var fileByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(bodyContent);

            var azureObjectsResource = new AzureObjectsResource(_connectionString, sharename, directory, filename, fileByteArray);

            var returnObject = await _fileServiceApplication.UploadFile(azureObjectsResource);

            return new OkObjectResult(returnObject);
        }
```

**FunctionalSpec.cs**

```
    public class FunctionalSpec :IClassFixture<FileServiceApplication>
    {
        private readonly IFileServiceApplication _fileServiceApplication;
        private readonly ILogger _log;

        public FunctionalSpec(IFileServiceApplication fileServiceApplication, ILogger log)
        {
            _fileServiceApplication = fileServiceApplication;
            _log = log;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task UploadFileSuccess()
        {
            // Arrange
            string contents = "test file contents!";
            string shareDirectory = "test1";
            string shareName = "teststorage";
            string fileName = "Test";
            string apiURL = "https://testfileshare.file.core.windows.net/testfileshare";
            string connectionString =
                "";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);

            var azureResource = new AzureObjectsResource(connectionString, shareName, shareDirectory, fileName, byteArray);

            await _fileServiceApplication?.UploadFile(azureResource)!;
        }
```

Comment: Why are *you* testing Azure storage?

Comment: @stuartd I wanted to test and ensure the functionality between the azure function code and file storage does not break if someone makes changes.